# What is the full explanation for Lala's appearance?

Tags: knights-of-sidonia

The [wiki article for the *Knights of Sidonia* character Lala](http://sidonia-no-kishi.wikia.com/wiki/Lala_Hiyama) says:

> Lala Hiyama (ヒ山 ララァ Hiyama Rarā) is a human who is wearing a bear-like life support suit to sustain herself.

In the anime, the appearance is very similar to:

[image]

Does the manga provide a deeper explanation here?  She seems unique in her ... form, and that form seems especially peculiar given the level of acceptable genetic engineering on the show.  In fact, in the context of the show it almost seems plausible that she is a *humanoid bear* as much as *human wearing a bear suit*.

If this is a "bear-like support suit" - it begs two questions: why does she need a support suit, and why is it a bear?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no canon explanation for either question.

Comment: ***"Lala’s design is a callback to Nihei’s manga, Biomega; Kozlov, a supporting character, is also a bear and lost his hand."***

Answer (score 3):

Why it is a bear, is most likely just the Author's preference.

The exact reason for the life support suit is revealed in a latter chapter:

> There is a scene showing Lala, Saito Hiroki, and Ochiai, with Lala in a life supporting chamber. They talked about Gauna's placenta invading her brain, presumably by injuries from a battle; though there's no adverse effects, she will die without life support, and they weren't able to cure her with their available tech, so Ochiai made her a suit. From the appearance of Ochiai, this episode likely happened at least 7 centuries ago. And, the location of her complication probably prevented an easy body swap.

Why does it have to be a bear?

> Again there's no canon explanation for that. But probably from the need to fit the whole or part of Lala's body inside and the relatively humanoid shape and size of a bear. In the above scene, it also shows a similar suit with a transparent dome shaped helmet, you can see Lala wearing it, that almost resembles the bear but mechanical looking, with the iconic mechanical rotating hand.

Comment: Yes, the bear is likely the author's preference, but why is it a bear in-universe?

Comment: @phantom42 Again there's no canon explanation for that. But probably from the need to fit the whole or part of Lala's body inside and the relatively humanoid shape and size of a bear.

Answer (score 0):

It's also Kobayashis punishment for her disobedience at certain key points. At least that's what I gathered from only watching the Anime and the latest Movie (that we got instead of an awesome season 3).

Comment: Was that actually stated in the anime or movie? If so, you could greatly improve this answer by editing it to include any relevant quotes.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's like Kobayashis mask, used to hide their immortality to the public.

Comment: Why do you think that?